# Allow POST method

Tags: graphhopper

I need to change the request method that is sent to GraphHopper to a POST method. Indeed I send so many points that the GET one crashes. POST requests do not seem to be allowed since I get a 405 error from the server.
How can I allow to send POST method ? Where is the jetty configuration handled ?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not a jetty config. You'll have to implement 'doPost' in the GraphHopperServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a jetty config. You'll have to implement 'doPost' in the GraphHopperServlet